# How to move tracking History from one object to another?

Tags: visualforce, data-export

Hi i am transferring the records from one object to another using data loader. I want to transfer the history tracking information for particular records also. How can i achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't allow DML opearation on the History objects. Please open up a ticket with Premiere support and check if they can enable it for a particular time window for you to complete the migration. Here is a screenshot of AccountHistory table which shows most of the information is locked:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i am using custom object for capturing History for audit purpose. How can i transfer the standard history to custom history object.

Comment: You can pull a report on the history object and extract the report into an excel Or you can use workbench. So if your object is a standard object e.g. Account or Lead the history object name would be AccountHistory, LeadHistory etc. However if it's a custom object , let's say CustomObject__c then the name of History object would be CustomObject__History.

Comment: Once you see the schema of the object you will have an idea as to how to design your new Custom table to capture. Let me know if you need more details on Dataloader or other tools for migration